# Micro Watt Meter in Extreme Low Temperature

Tags: temperature, solar-energy, power-meter

I'm using a solar panel in the Arctic and I want to measure the power it delivers to the associated sensors. Is there any recommendation on a watt meter for this environment? The temperature is expected to be lower than -50 Celsius degrees. The voltage ~10V and current ~10mA.

Comment: Like a product you can buy? Or a circuit?

Comment: will the solar panel operate at the low temperature?

Comment: I’ve worked up there below -40 and the solar time is pretty short in winter and direction suboptimal in summer (360 deg) I hope you have other power sources and silver oxide batteries.

Comment: @laptop2d I mean a product ready to use, and tolerant to a temperature lower than -50 cencius degrees.

Comment: @jsotola Not so good as effective time is really limited. Therefore we also install a rechargable battery.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Precisely. We do have a battery, it works well in the winter so far.

Comment: There's no reason why @Jack's answer with the INA226 won't work at -50'C but you will have to calibrate it for gain and offset error.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks. What about the MCU, like Atmel AVR328P, do you think it also works in -50'C?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I am also curious about possible cracks in extremely low temperature because the WiFI-LTE modem we deployed lost its connection. We are still not sure about the reason. A trip to Arctic in September this year may give some clues.

Comment: They lost (lol) my VLF signal too in the Beaufort Sea when the automated floating weather station launched in'76? ended up in Siberia some 8 yrs later .  Thermal stress works in many ways popcorn effect rising above 0'C from plastic seal leak or moisture ingress, CTE shear stress on wirebonds, dielectric shift in freq. Polar bears (j/k) I thought climate was warmer now?  But our uplink to GOES 1 still worked. My doppler design just lost position signals from US Navy VLF. (after I moved on)

Comment: Bears and wolves were within our suspections before we saw the facilities were visually perfect lol... I expected the shutdown to be reversible but it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Datalogging etc is probably what you want to do, but if you wanted no software, or extreme low power, this is an option:

If you measured current after the regulator, or at a fairly constant voltage point, then you would simply need to integrate current.

This can be done without using a microprocessor using an integrator type voltage-freq convertor, and a counter. In the extreme case using micropower opamp and comparator below, it will draw less than 1uA, while running continuously.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWOkJc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BTW, because this converter is truly integrating the current in C1, it can accurate measure the current drain of intermittant loads that are sleeping and waking.

To directly integrate power:

- R5 can be made inverse proportional to voltage (R~1/V), then it becomes a multiplying power meter. A pwm of R5 with duty cycle 1/V can do this.
- If REF can be 1/V (over the limited working range) then it will integrate power. Note that V is effectively sampled only when the integrator resets. [suggestions for a 1/V circuit welcome]

C1 polypropylene or polystyrene preferably. Certainly low leakage.
R2C2 delay ensures C1 can be reset. reset switch is low leakage.

PCF8593 I2C clock chip can also be configured as a counter, which you could read out at any later (warmer and better powered) time.

If you were using a micro, this is still a nice low power current integrating current sensor, which integrates the current even when the uP is asleep. If input leakage current is low enough, then the io pins can be used as a reset switch, and using a comparator keeps the cpu operations quick. So you only need R1,5,Amp1,C1. All analog functions can sleep during integration, so total current including th uP could be under 5uA

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1EOSV.png)</sup>

Comment: Wow this is genius, thanks Henry! (clapping right now lol)

Comment: Very smart circuit indeed, but are you sure about current consumption? LMV821 alone seems to take around 200uA  quiescent if I read well.

Comment: Even if indeed there are other parts with such a low quiescent current, this page http://www.ti.com/product/LMV821-N seems to rule LMV821 out.

Comment: My bad, LPV821 http://www.ti.com/product/LPV821

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to measure the power output under development and test conditions, and not in the field.

By far the easiest way is to use a [TI INA226](http://www.ti.com/product/ina226) breakout board connected to a small MCU for logging. The ideal MCU is perhaps an Arduino Pro mini, Nano or Micro, which are all readily available.

You can get the INA226 on a board from Amazon or Ebay.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for your help. Actually I expect it to work in the field, to record the power consumption all year round. That's why I am looking for a model for extremely low temperature. TI INA226 seems good for -40, but Arduino not.

Comment: It will work, but needs to be calibrated for low power and thus low offset and gain error.

Comment: @Shawn You said the voltage is about 10V and the current 10mA, if you want to log in the field you'd need a very low power solution indeed, but I think the Atmel AVR 328P could be ideal along with the INA226. The power budget for both is well under 1mA (at lower clock speeds) and could be much less if you sleep most of the time. More critical seems to be that both are graded to -40C, so don't quite meet your requirements.

Comment: @jackcreasey Yeah the consumption of the monitoring system should be low enough. And it can be further reduced by evokibg less. The temperature grading is really a problem in our case as the lowest temp in Arctic is definitely below -40. Maybe we should build it up and test it in Lab. I am really curious about NASA's choice in space, or adventurers' solution in Antactica...

Comment: The -40C is just a recommendation with  a deviation to specs for gain error in ppm etc. below this, which can be easily calibrated.  There's no physical stress threshold until below -65'C for storage. Just put some dry ice on the chip and test it, although less thermal shock is better.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You'd certainly have to do a bunch of testing to gain confidence at -50C. The biggest problem is selecting a ceramic resonator, low temperature and low voltage can give problems. But if the voltage is kept higher (3.3 or 5V) then it should be possible to end up with a reliable starts.

Comment: Xtals should be more robust and freq  stability is unlikely to pose challenges. My experience has been over wider temp ranges up to 500 miles high on the Black Brandt series in instrument design. https://sites.wff.nasa.gov/code810/files/Sounding_Rockets_Annual_Report_2016.pdf

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist True, crystals can be better, again providing the oscillator is at a reasonably high voltage. I've used a lot of Expresso's with extended temperature range at 3.3V, but the current budget is a killer at 30+ mA

Comment: As I recall 20 mA was my entire power budget for a 5 channel Rx for Doppler Nav in the Arctic

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist ...but at what operating voltage? 20mA is meaningless unless you know the operating voltage. At 5V it's 0.1W, at 3.3V it's 66mW and at 1.8V it's 36mW.

Comment: It was all 5V CMOS, BJT’s  PLL’s with 5 simultaneous active Rx’s 5deg X cut Xtal filters      Tracking navy VLF but as I recall I was week under budget on power

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist The NASA document is really helpful. Thanks a lot.